# Joining Pandas Dataframes on Column Name Matches Row Value (with same index)

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this:

```
              ID     Col1    Col2
2018-06-01    'A'     10     100
2018-06-02    'B'     5      25
2018-06-03    'A'     25     25
```

and another dataframe that looks like:

```
               A      B        C
2018-06-01    0.5     1.1      1
2018-06-02    0.75    2.1      1
2018-06-03    0.6     0.3      0
```

and I want to merge them in pandas where the indices (dates in this case) match, and the values in the rows under the ID column match the column names in the second dataframe. Easier to just show it, it would look like this:

```
              ID     Col1    Col2     NEW
2018-06-01    'A'     10     100      0.5
2018-06-02    'B'     5      25       2.1
2018-06-03    'A'     25     25       0.6
```

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this in pandas, but I can't think of what it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `lookup`

```
df1['New']=df2.lookup(df1.index,df1.ID)
df1
Out[14]: 
           ID  Col1  Col2  New
2018-06-01  A    10   100  0.5
2018-06-02  B     5    25  2.1
2018-06-03  A    25    25  0.6
```