# Pandas DataFrame.lookup

Tags: python, pandas

is there a decent example how to use Pandas [DataFrame.lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

Yes I saw this but not sure what's the point... it seems it's just selecting the price column:
[vectorized-look-up-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893227/vectorized-look-up-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

So to explain what i mean,

```
columns=['AAPL','GOOG','IBM','XOM']
index = ['2011-01-10','2011-01-13','2011-01-26','2011-02-02','2011-02-10','2011-03-03','2011-05-03','2011-06-03','2011-06-10','2011-08-01','2011-12-20']
prices = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=index)
prices.iloc[0]=[339.441,614.219,142.781,71.571]
prices.iloc[1]=[342.642,616.698,143.922,73.083]
prices.iloc[2]=[340.823,616.507,155.743,75.895]
prices.iloc[3]=[341.294,612.006,157.934,79.467]
prices.iloc[4]=[351.425,616.445,159.325,79.689]
prices.iloc[5]=[356.406,609.564,158.736,82.192]
prices.iloc[6]=[345.147,533.893,167.847,82.004]
prices.iloc[7]=[340.428,523.082,160.978,78.196]
prices.iloc[8]=[323.039,509.511,159.149,76.848]
prices.iloc[9]=[393.261,606.779,176.281,76.671]
prices.iloc[10]=[392.462,630.378,184.142,79.973]

columns=['Date','direction','size','ticker','tradePrices']
orders = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
orders.loc[0] = ['2011-01-10','Buy',1500,'AAPL',339.44]
orders.loc[1] = ['2011-01-13','Sell',1500,'AAPL',342.64]
orders.loc[2] = ['2011-01-13','Buy',4000,'IBM',143.92]
orders.loc[3] = ['2011-01-26','Buy',1000,'GOOG',616.50]
orders.loc[4] = ['2011-02-02','Sell',4000,'XOM',79.46]
orders.loc[5] = ['2011-02-10','Buy',4000,'XOM',79.68]
orders.loc[6] = ['2011-03-03','Sell',1000,'GOOG',609.56]
orders.loc[7] = ['2011-03-03','Sell',2200,'IBM',158.73]
orders.loc[8] = ['2011-06-03','Sell',3300,'IBM',160.97]
orders.loc[9] = ['2011-05-03','Buy',1500,'IBM',167.84]
orders.loc[10] = ['2011-06-10','Buy',1200,'AAPL',323.03]
orders.loc[11] = ['2011-08-01','Buy',55,'GOOG',606.77]
orders.loc[12] = ['2011-08-01','Sell',55,'GOOG',606.77]
orders.loc[13] = ['2011-12-20','Sell',1200,'AAPL',392.46]

lookupValues = prices.lookup(orders.Date, orders.ticker)
```

Then the result is,

```
>>> prices
               AAPL     GOOG      IBM     XOM
2011-01-10  339.441  614.219  142.781  71.571
2011-01-13  342.642  616.698  143.922  73.083
2011-01-26  340.823  616.507  155.743  75.895
2011-02-02  341.294  612.006  157.934  79.467
2011-02-10  351.425  616.445  159.325  79.689
2011-03-03  356.406  609.564  158.736  82.192
2011-05-03  345.147  533.893  167.847  82.004
2011-06-03  340.428  523.082  160.978  78.196
2011-06-10  323.039  509.511  159.149  76.848
2011-08-01  393.261  606.779  176.281  76.671
2011-12-20  392.462  630.378  184.142  79.973
>>> orders
          Date direction  size ticker  prices
0   2011-01-10       Buy  1500   AAPL  339.44
1   2011-01-13      Sell  1500   AAPL  342.64
2   2011-01-13       Buy  4000    IBM  143.92
3   2011-01-26       Buy  1000   GOOG  616.50
4   2011-02-02      Sell  4000    XOM   79.46
5   2011-02-10       Buy  4000    XOM   79.68
6   2011-03-03      Sell  1000   GOOG  609.56
7   2011-03-03      Sell  2200    IBM  158.73
8   2011-06-03      Sell  3300    IBM  160.97
9   2011-05-03       Buy  1500    IBM  167.84
10  2011-06-10       Buy  1200   AAPL  323.03
11  2011-08-01       Buy    55   GOOG  606.77
12  2011-08-01      Sell    55   GOOG  606.77
13  2011-12-20      Sell  1200   AAPL  392.46
>>> prices.lookup(orders.Date, orders.ticker)
array([339.441, 342.642, 143.922, 616.507,  79.467,  79.689, 609.564,
       158.736, 160.978, 167.847, 323.039, 606.779, 606.779, 392.462])
```

I could have just use "loc" to retrieve only "price" column of "orders":

```
>>> orders.loc[:,['prices']]
    prices
0   339.44
1   342.64
2   143.92
3   616.50
4    79.46
5    79.68
6   609.56
7   158.73
8   160.97
9   167.84
10  323.03
11  606.77
12  606.77
13  392.46
```

The question is - what's the point of "DataFrame.lookup"? And there must be a proper usage?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547598/joining-pandas-dataframes-on-column-name-matches-row-value-with-same-index/52547708#52547708

Answer (score 0):

Expected output was included in the `order` dataframe of the original post  , you can assuming there is ***no*** `price` column in order , if so using `lookup` is a nice way for get that value

```
orders['price']= prices.lookup(orders.Date, orders.ticker)
```

Also you can using `loc` or for loop here

```
orders.apply(lambda x : prices.loc[x['Date'],x['ticker']],axis=1)
Out[116]: 
0     339.44
1     342.64
2     143.92
3     616.50
4      79.46
5      79.68
6     609.56
7     158.73
8     160.97
9     167.84
10    323.03
11    606.77
12    606.77
13    392.46
dtype: float64

[prices.loc[x,y] for x , y in zip(orders.Date,orders.ticker)]
Out[118]: 
[339.44,
 342.64,
 143.92,
 616.5,
 79.46,
 79.68,
 609.56,
 158.73,
 160.97,
 167.84,
 323.03,
 606.77,
 606.77,
 392.46]
```

Comment: I'm checking out "lookup" because i was told "apply" is not vectorized (i.e. slower): https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **Wen**, I see the point now, we add **"streetPrices"** (from **"prices"**) to **"orders"**:

```
orders['streetPrices'] = prices.lookup(orders.Date, orders.ticker)

>>> orders
          Date direction  size ticker  tradePrices  streetPrices 
0   2011-01-10       Buy  1500   AAPL  339.44    339.441
1   2011-01-13      Sell  1500   AAPL  342.64    342.642
2   2011-01-13       Buy  4000    IBM  143.92    143.922
3   2011-01-26       Buy  1000   GOOG  616.50    616.507
4   2011-02-02      Sell  4000    XOM   79.46     79.467
5   2011-02-10       Buy  4000    XOM   79.68     79.689
6   2011-03-03      Sell  1000   GOOG  609.56    609.564
7   2011-03-03      Sell  2200    IBM  158.73    158.736
8   2011-06-03      Sell  3300    IBM  160.97    160.978
9   2011-05-03       Buy  1500    IBM  167.84    167.847
10  2011-06-10       Buy  1200   AAPL  323.03    323.039
11  2011-08-01       Buy    55   GOOG  606.77    606.779
12  2011-08-01      Sell    55   GOOG  606.77    606.779
13  2011-12-20      Sell  1200   AAPL  392.46    392.462
>>>
```

Question still,

```
orders['streetPrices'] = prices.lookup(orders.Date, orders.ticker)
```

Arg1 = orders.Date = prices DataFrame **index**

Arg2 = orders.ticker = prices DataFrame **columns**

Can you have multiple cascading index?

Thanks

Comment: When you have multi-index'es. For above example, index on price table is just date. What if we have multi index {date, exchange}? Two level indexes now.

Comment: I think lookup is not support the multiple index , you may check above solution then :-)